# System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL with dotnet core

Tags: c++, c, linux, .net-core

I've been tasked with calling openzwave from dotnet core on linux and i'm having issues with dotnet core loading my c++ library. Essentially any time i touch the openzwave library I get a dll not found exception.
here's my program.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace MinOZWDotNet
    {
        public class Program
        {

            [DllImport("MinOZW")]
            public static extern int Init();

            [DllImport("MinOZW")]
            public static extern int Free();

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Calling Init");
                var val= Init();
                Console.WriteLine($"retval= {val}");

                while (true)
                {

                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {

                        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();

                        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Exit");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Calling Free");
                val = Free();
                Console.WriteLine($"retval = {val}");

            }
        }
    }
```

heres a version of the .so which works

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
        #define EXPORT extern "C"
        #define CC
#else
        #define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
        #define CC __stdcall
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "Defs.h"

#else

#include "Windows.h"

#endif



EXPORT int CC Init() {

        return 0;
}

EXPORT int CC Free() {

        return 0;
}
```

heres the version which is giving me the error

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
        #define EXPORT extern "C"
        #define CC
#else
        #define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
        #define CC __stdcall
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "Defs.h"

#else

#include "Windows.h"

#endif


#include "Options.h"
#include "Manager.h"
#include "Driver.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Group.h"
#include "Notification.h"
#include "value_classes/ValueStore.h"
#include "value_classes/Value.h"
#include "value_classes/ValueBool.h"
#include "platform/Log.h"

using namespace OpenZWave;


EXPORT int CC Init() {
        Manager::Create();
        return 0;
}

EXPORT int CC Free() {
        Manager::Destroy();
        return 0;
}
```

both openzwave and this lib are on the expected path. 
N.B when compiled on windows this all works.
[openZwave on github](https://github.com/OpenZWave/open-zwave/tree/master/cpp/examples/MinOZW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use your lib inside a C program? Maybe that OpenZWave has some dependencies that are missing on linux...

Comment: I took this source from the MinOZW example which builds executable and modified it as shown. The executable works on linux.

Comment: Well this exception (reading the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dllnotfoundexception.aspx)) is thrown because CRL can't find "MinOZW.so", firstly I thought it was a "case sensitive" issue but you have a version that works so I excluded it...

Comment: I guess I need to make the linker look for the non-versioned libopenzwave when its building my c library. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!!.
I made a c++ program which called the .so which pointed me to the issue :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*moo)();

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  void* myso = dlopen("/home/mark/open-zwave/.lib/MinOZW.so", RTLD_NOW );


//  void* myso = dlopen("/home/mark/open-zwave/libopenzwave.so", RTLD_NOW);

  if (!myso){
    std::cout << "Failed to load lib " << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

//  moo func =(moo) dlsym(myso, "Free");

//  func();

  dlclose(myso);

  return 0;
}
```

> g++ -o main main.cpp -ldl
> ./main
>
> Hello World!
>
> Failed to load lib
>
> libopenzwave.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory

One quick sym link later and it all works :)

Comment: In general, you want to load from the versioned SONAME, not the unversioned one.  Most distros will do things like symlink libfoo.so.1.1 -> libfoo.so.1.2 if 1.2 had no breaking changes; but your reference should be to libfoo.so.1.1 since that's the API set you used.