# Seg fault with Dotnetcore and callbacks

Tags: c#, c++, ubuntu, .net-core

Firstly some background, this question follows on from [System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL with dotnet core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871068/system-dllnotfoundexception-unable-to-load-dll-with-dotnet-core).

We managed to fully implement a interop facade which works in windows. However we have been having issues running in linux. We keep getting segment faults randomly. It sometimes works for minutes or hours but eventually it dies.
Here are some code snippets. 
N.B `OnNotificationFromUnmanaged` does more than just log however we have found that no matter what it contains even void this is still the point at which the app dies.

c#

```
private void OnNotificationFromUnmanaged(ZWNotification notification)
{
    Console.WriteLine ( "OnNotificationFromUnmanaged");
}

var callback = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((ManagedNotificationsHandler)OnNotificationFromUnmanaged);
Console.WriteLine($"Callback Ptr = {callback}");

Interop.RegisterCallback(callback);
GC.Collect();//all calls should now segfault should the callback get GC'd
```

cpp

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define EXPORT extern "C"
#define CC
#else
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)
#define CC __stdcall
#endif



typedef void(CC *CallBackDelegate)(ZWNotification);

CallBackDelegate cb; //set by another function


void OnNotification ( Notification const* _notification, void* _context)
{

        ZWNotification zw;
        ...init stuff here

        Log::Write( LogLevel_Info, "Callback to C#, %p", cb);

        if ( cb)
                cb ( zw);
        Log::Write( LogLevel_Info, "Callback to C# - done");

}
```

On failure we get:

> 2017-03-27 15:53:22.005 Info, Callback to C#, 0x7fe2184175fc 
>   $

```
dmesg reveals
```

> [ 7383.514872] dotnet[21218]: segfault at 7fe218418000 ip
>   00007fe218418000 sp 00007fe0ebffec88 error 14

We've noticed that the fault always happens in the 1k range after the end of the unmanaged ptr we're not sure if this is significant at all.
For example:

```
>     segfault at 7f72c17f4000 ip 00007f72c17f4000 sp 00007f718d0fac88 error 14
>     segfault at 7f1656b75000 ip 00007f1656b75000 sp 00007f152d50bc88 error 14
```

Any ideas are very welcome! At this point we've kinda lost the will to live.

> `uname -a`
>   Linux dh-vm-ubuntu01 4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
>   Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> `dotnet --version`
>   2.0.0-preview1-005416

Comment: Since your OnNotificationFromUnmanaged is not static  - maybe it's instance getting garbage collected?

Comment: Its a class private function. The class is a singleton. Can you post an example as an answer, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Just a thought. If it's a singleton, it's instance is stored in static field and so cannot be collected.

Comment: I have added GC.Collect() after Interop.RegisterCallback(callback); and it appears to still be working

Comment: Although after the change its yet to crash! haha!...it will though (famous last words)

Comment: As promised it crashed after a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

As per @Evk's comment I altered the code slightly

```
        private ManagedNotificationsHandler Handler;
```

.....

```
Handler += OnNotificationFromUnmanaged;

var callback = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(Handler);
Interop.RegisterCallback(callback);
```

and that appears to have fixed it.